# How to implement sessions and logout in a react+node web application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, session, jwt, session-cookies

I am creating a webapp using  nodejs backend and reactjs frontend with a mysql database, where each user has their own separate set of data.

I need to maintain sessions to identify users(for example, which user clicked the reset password button) whilst also implementing the logout feature (necessary).

I have read articles stating that logout with jwt defeats the purpose as it requires storing tokens on database.

I am confused whether to use cookies(way less secure) or jwt with database for maintaining sessions as I have never implemented this before.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) , when an user is authentified, you send back the token with a refresh token, that you store in your MySQL database, to your react app.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, I think, is to create jwt tokens, store them in cookies and then remove the cookie on logout, and hence not storing it in a database . I would still like to know other ways to do this.